# Where can I configure Ant 1.8's environment variables on an Ubuntu box?

Tags: java, ant, java-home

When trying to build with Ant, I'm getting an error that Ant can't find a compiler, and that JAVA_HOME is set to **/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-open-jdk/jre**.  An echo check reveals that JAVA_HOME is set to **/usr/local/lib/jdk1.6.0_22** (where Ant OUGHT to think it is, btw).  So the environment variables are *generally* right, but Ant apparently has its own ideas.  Is there a .conf file I can edit to knock some sense into this annoying build tool?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You typically put environment variables into your shell initialization files; e.g. `~/.bash-profile` or `~/.bashrc`, but you can also set then in system-wide files ... or in an *ad hoc* wrapper script.